# ¿Es posible conectar Google Forms con una página HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms

Tengo una sección de una página en la que quiero mostrar gráficas con los resultados de una encuesta de Google Forms, he estado mirando y no termino de entender si existe alguna manera de hacerlo, el código de la web sería algo así

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<div id="graficoContainer">
<p>Respuestas de la pregunta 1: </p>
<div id="grafico"></div>
</div>

//Supongo que el Js sería algo así (main.js)
var grafico = document.getElementById("grafico");

grafico.innerHTML = //Coge el gráfico desde Google Forms
```

Comment: Google Forms es simplemente una interfaz, los datos reales se guardan en una Hoja de Google. Entonces, puedes programar código para leer la Hoja de Google a la que está ligada el formulario y mostrar lo que necesites a partir de los datos. Esto puedes hacerlo desde el cliente, o desde el servidor, a través de la [API de Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api).

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe una API para acceder directamente a la gráficas de las respuestas de Google Forms pero hay varias opciones.

NOTA: Contrario a lo que algunos piensan los datos originals se guardan en un repositorio asociado al formulario. El enviar los datos a una hoja de cálculo de Google es opcional y cuando se vincula, los datos originales se mantiene en el repositorio asociado al formulario, así que se puede eliminar la hoja de cálculo o vincular el formulario a otra hoja de cálculo y los datos originales se mantienen.

1. Puedes usar el Class FormsApp de Google Apps Script para leer los datos de tu formulario sin necesidad de conectar el mismo a una hoja de cálculo.

   1. Podrías crear una web app con Google Apps Script y embeber esta en otra página web
   2. Podrías usar la API de Google Apps Script para conectar a Class FormsApp y que no tengas que publicar la web app con Google Apps Script
2. Si vinculas el formulario a una hoja de cálculo,

   1. puedes leer los datos de dicha hoja y leerlos usando Google Apps Script o la API de Google Sheets
   2. puedes crear las gráficas en dicha hoja y publicar estas a la web para luego incrustrarlas en tu hoja de cálculo.
   3. puedes usar la API de Google Charts, esta incluye métodos para leer los datos directamente de una hoja de cálculo